# FileStream slow, Fast way read read few bytes of many files

Tags: c#, .net-core, io, batch-processing, filestream

I need to read and process more than 100 millions of files, but I need to read only the first 4 bytes of each file, because I just need to read the header.
I already created a .net core 2.2 batch to process them, and I already use multithreading to maximize concurrent processing, but after all possible optimizations that I had in my mind it still takes too much time.
I did profiling benchmark and 78% of time is used to open the file stream: File.OpenRead(filePath).
For comparison File.Exist(filePath), and Director.Exist(dirPath) is much more faster.
Even the function Directory.GetFiles(dirPath) which I expected to be very slow, it takes only the 4% of global time of execution.

And another 15% of time is used to effectively read data from the stream.

I read from documentation that the default buffer size is of 4096 bytes, so first tried to reduce to 4 bytes, but I got no significative change in performance, but I think it's correct to keep 4096 because it's the cluster size of the file system.

The volume is a network drive accessed with CIFS protocol, but the files are saved on several physical disks.

Why is it so slow to just opening the stream? maybe because it needs to check user permissions?

Can you suggest a faster approach to access to all files?

Comment: Probably the reason is realated to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27265510/5081328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileStream is slower than other other API, like File.Exist, Directory.GetFiles, etc.., because it does a lot of SMB calls to normalize path, demands permissions, etc

You can get a better answer there [Why is .NET's File.Open with a UNC path making excessive SMB calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137267/why-is-nets-file-open-with-a-unc-path-making-excessive-smb-calls/27265510#27265510)

So the best way to speedup a stream is to call native API directly avoiding most of controls.

I found this good library that works pretty well: https://github.com/i-e-b/tinyQuickIO

Th only problem with that library it is that doesn't target .NET Core or .NET standard, but if you use it under windows it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is time for my Multitasking Disclaimer:

One alternate task you run the loop that goves over the files is pretty much standard. If nothing else, just to not lock up the main/GUI thread.

But Multittasking in all it's forms is not a magical "make things faster" bullet. If you apply it to the wrong problem, you end up with code that is more complex/more prone to error, more memory demanding and most importantly *slower* then simple sequential code.

Now file processing is usually a disk or network bound operation. You only get 4 bytes, so I guess you are not doing a lot of custom CPU work per file. So the only CPU work here will be the opening and closing of the handles. Wich I am pretty sure is close to nothing unless you use some [antique like PIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmed_input/output) for the disks/Network. So also Disk/Network bound.

There are a few fringe cases with connections over the internet and per-connection limits, but I doubt they apply here. And generally per-file Multitasking is not speeding anything up.

Comment: I am not sure, because in fact with multithreading it is about 20% faster, I get the best improvement with 2 threads, with more than 4 threads the increase is trivial, and with more than 8 threads is useless since the previous thread terminates before I can start a new thread.

Comment: But yes I understand, this is has nothing to do with disk I/O, simple I get better performances because while I wait the result from I/O operation, I can do my other elaborations and write the results on a database.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti I guess the 20% is because you got some gaps in the useage of the Network. HDD's are slow. But the Network still manages to be slower then it. | The only real speedup is going to cut the Network out. You need to either get the Disk to the Code, or the Code to the disk.

Comment: Anyway what are you saying I think it applies only if all operations are made on a single physical disk, the volume is one, but the operations are made on several disks with RAID. I am not very sure of the architecture, since I access from newtork drive, but for sure there are several physical disks. and why can't I access two files in two different disks in parallel?

Comment: and I don't think the network is slow, because if the problem is the network, all operations on the disk will be slow, for example File.Exist, but file.Exist execution time is insignificant. The only very slow operation is FileStream.Open

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti There are very different kinds of Raids, and with the exception of Raid 0, they are usually designed for reliability over speed. With Raid 1's there can be read speed improovements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Standard_levels | Not that this really maters, because really the network will be the bottleneck. The disks might at worst have some spin-up time. | File.Exist needs very litle data and no file handles. It jsut touches the uppermost layer of the file system - the list of files, their names/paths/rights. Read access goes way deeper.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti The transmission speeds can be confusing. Because sometimes they are given in Bit/s, and sometimes in Bytes/s. Also somtimes with the 1024 multiplier and sometimes with the 1000. And for the network, you got the include all the overhead of 4-6 layers of protocolls. For Disks those are usually factored in (as they are pretty constant).

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti With HDD's physical access times having stalled basically for decades now, Networks have almost caught up. With RAID and SSD, it is still clearly on the Disk side. Actually something that I heard off, was people putting a extra Disk Controler in the "GPU" slot. Because the normal SATA connectors are too slow or you got way to few of them.

Comment: I am not very sure of what are you saying, here I am accessing to a virtual drive in a datacenter, unlucky I don't know what architecture they use, but several PetaBytes of files are stored in this volume. I feel you are saying something like Horizontal scalability is useless for filesystem access.

Comment: They are called "PCIe SSD" cards if you want to look them up, its not always the GPU slot but some very high end ones could require 16x PCIe which is what the GPU uses.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti How have you done your multi-threading? Don't create threads, because this takes a very long time. Use `Parallel.For/ForEach` instead, which is highly optimized in that it finds the optimal amount of threads and reuses old ones instead of creating new ones.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti Wait, it is in a DataCenter? As in "the connection goes over the Internet, via a tunnel or otherwise"? How fast is that connection?

Comment: @ckuri, no I don't use Parallel, because I need to optimize the number of threads with the necessity of the application. I load chunks of 1000 paths from  a db, then I loop them, I start a new Thread, inside the threads I elaborate and write result in a ConcurrentQueue. then I undload elaborated data into sql server. But if the queue has more than 100 elaborated files, I stop creating threads until I unload some of them in the database. Everything is syncronized with a semaphoreslim and max amount of threads. Even if I set 32 as max number, usually it doesn't create more than 8 threads.

Comment: @ckuri but reuse of threads can be really a good idea to save memory instead to create new istances, I'll think about. Anyway I assure you that this approach is very fast, the bottleneck is just FileStrea.Open

Comment: @Christopher the datacenter is here, just a different floor of the company from wich I am working, later I try to talk with system administrator to understand the situation.
The batch is deployed directly on a server in the datacenter, connection is very fast, I think Gigabit, but here I did profiling with Visual studio profiler from my machine.
From my machine is a bit slower, because I need to pass throught a proxy and authenticate to enter in the DMZ.

Comment: They asked me to try to make the batch multiprocess instead of multithtreading, so they can launch of different servers. But I told them that to do that I need to lock the table in the database to avoid multiple elaboration of same files, so everything will be slower.
They say that I/O and network usage on the server is very low, but I don't believe to them, anyway I guess the problem is not the server where the batch is deployed, but it's in the storage servers.